# Error during replication from Oracle to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-replication

I am implementing a replication from Oracle 12c server to SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition.

I have set up the Publisher successfully. .

I am bringing in 2 table elements into SQL Server. These contain date fields

[Refer Date Field Mapping done on Publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xspGH.png)

The Subscription gets created fine and when the replication agent runs for the first time, I am facing following error:

Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent ServerName-TNSNAME-PublisherName-1 failed. The process could not bulk copy into table '"dbo"."Destinationtable"'.

The SQL Logs at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log contain the minidump of the process when it failed. They mention that SQLSERVR.exe faced a fatal exception

> Dump File:    SQLDump0004.mdmp : C:\LOgs\SQLDump0004.mdmp
>
> Last Write Time:  5/12/2016 11:02:15 PM
>
> Process Name: sqlservr.exe : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>
> Exception Code:   0xC0000005 Exception Information:   The thread tried to
>   read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the
>   appropriate access. SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 66 generated
>   fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is
>   terminating this process.

Need help going past this error.